# Password field color

Tags: swing

I want to change the color of my JPasswordField with key Listener. I'm making a registration form and the user should fill the passwordfield at least with 8 characters that include digits and letters. Can anybody help me?

my code :

```
enter code here

 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==passwordField){
        if(passwordField.toString().length()>=8)
            passwordField.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        else
            passwordField.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us the code you tried please

Comment: what have you tried and what/how isn't working as expected? Please show a SSCCE that demonstrates your problem

Answer (score 1):

When the keyPressed() event is fired the Document of the password field has not yet been updated, so the length will be 1 less than you think it should be.

Instead try using the `keyTyped()` method:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
{
    JPasswordField password = (JPasswordField)e.getSource();

    if(passwordField.getPassword().length >= 8)
        passwordField.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    else
        passwordField.setBackground(Color.RED);
}
```

Also, when writing a listener you should get the source of the event from the event object instead of trying to access an instance variable.

You may also want to consider using an `InputVerifier` on this field. The input verifier will prevent the user from tab away from this field unless at least 8 digits have been entered.

Note: even using the keyTyped() event you can still have problems because if the user uses the "BackSpace" key no event is generated. So maybe you should be using the keyRelased() event. Even this can cause a problem because if the users holds down a key multiple characters will be entered into the field before a keyReleased event is fired.

The best solution is to use a Document Listener. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

you're doing it wrong

change to this

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==passwordField){
        if(passwordField.getPassword().length()>=8)
            passwordField.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        else
            passwordField.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

}
```

you should use `getPassword()`